# Content Elements - too many elements causing problems

Tags: content-elements

So I am running into an interesting problem.  I have an article that, within 'Content Elements' (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements) field there are over 50 elements.

When I save a revision, it reloads the article and the 'Content Elements' field is now empty.  The other EE fields (thumbnail, url-title) still appear however.
What's interesting is that if I go to Revisions, and load a prior revision (where the same issue happened), all of the properly saved content elements fields appear.  Moreover, if I load the latest revision (again, where Content Elements was blank after save), all of the data properly appears.  So the data is all being saved properly, it's just not being shown.

When I try to view the page (via Live Look), none of the Content Elements data is shown though.

If I go back to Content->Edit->Entry, the Content Elements is again blank (other EE fields like thumbnail and url-title load fine). I have to load a previous revision first, and then load the most recent revision again in order to see the latest Content Elements data.

So I tried shortening my article, by removing about 10 elements inside the Content Elements field.  This brought the article closer to ~40 elements.  Presto! It all works as it should.  So it appears it's something to do with the amount of elements I'm using inside Content Elements.

Curious if anyone has run into this before? Any suggestions on trying to debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your php max_vars environment value set at? Add a zero to the end!

Comment: max_input_vars is set to 1000. I would think that would be large enough? If I view source on the article there are 272 input's.  Again, all of the data is actually being saved properly, it's just not being re-displayed in the 'Edit Entry'

Comment: Ahh, are you getting **JavaScript** errors in your web browsers developer console (F12) when you go to edit_entry and the problem presents?

Comment: Nope, no JS errors that I see when saving or loading.

Comment: Looks like this is the same issue as http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/update-content-elements-and-issues-with-unserialize?rq=1 , I removed the @ in the unserialize() call and I get "unserialize() Error at offset..."